# How can I load nwjs binary file at server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/protect-javascript-source-code-with-v8-snapshot

generate binary file:

```
nwjc source.js binary.bin
```

load binary.bin at client side:
Using **require('nw.gui').Window.get().evalNWBin();**

```
<html><head>
  <title>snapshot demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  require('nw.gui').Window.get().evalNWBin(null, 'binary.bin');
  // call function...
  </script>
</body></html>
```

How can I load binary.bin at server side?

And can I fork a child process to run binary file?

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var sourceProcess = childProcess.fork('source.js');
var binaryProcess = childProcess.fork('binary.bin');  // ??
```